# How Do I Keep All Series Labels on a 3D chart

Tags: charts, spreadsheetgear

Suppose that I have a list of 40 planets (OK some are from another solar system). Astronomers have counted the number of meteors hitting the planets from January to December. So I have 40 rows of 12 columns of data.

When I plot a 3D chart the planets are displayed on the depth axis, the months January to December are on the Category axis, and the number of meteors on the value axis.

But some of the planets are missing. It seems `SpreadsheetGear` or `Excel` is treating the planets like numbers.

How do make `SpreadsheetGear` display all planets on the depth axis?

PS. I reviewed all related `Spreadsheetgear` docs but I couldn't find how to do this and checked StackOverflow for related questions but didn't find any.

Thanks, CoolBreeze

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved my own problem:

1) I increased the width of the chart when I called AddChart:

```
   ChartObj = m_WorksheetObj.Shapes.AddChart(Left, Top, Width, Height).Chart
```

2) I set TackLabelSpacing = 1

```
    Dim DepthAxis As IAxis = ChartObj.Axes(AxisType.Series)
    DepthAxis.TickLabelSpacing = 1
```

I'm not sure if that is the best solution but it appears to work for me at the moment.

If I add more planets the labels will be closer together and it'll be harder to read the labels. I'll have to widen the chart some more to spread out the labels to make them easier to read.

I added numbers in front of the planet names so when I looked at the list of planets on the chart I could see 1-40 and I knew all planets were listed.